# Программно нажать на кнопку на сайте

Tags: javascript, c++

Доброго времени суток. Необходимо реализовать небольшого бота на C++, который будет ковырять один сайт. Дело в том, что некоторые кнопки на сайте являются AJAX (м.б. написал глупость, но я надеюсь Вы меня поняли), как я понимаю простым post запросом не обойтись (если я ошибаюсь, пожалуйста, подправьте). Каким же методом можно их нажимать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ajax - это тот же самый POST-запрос.

Алгоритм действий простой:

1. Разбираем все запросы сайта. Для этого подойдет Firebug например;
2. Переносим отдачу этих запросов в программу.

Все запросы отправляются браузером GET/POST, никаких других методов нет (Flash - отдельная история) и отслеживаются эти запросы просто Firebug`ом.